# Can you retrieve the facetime call history?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, facetime

I think I know the answer, but I want to make absolutely sure. Can you programmatically get the call history of facetime? My app can start a facetime call and I'd like to log the duration. It doesn't return to the app after the call, so I would like to retrieve facetime's history.
If someone knows of a way to return to the app after the facetime call, that would be good as well, because then I can make my own call history.
I currently use this code to start the facetime call:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"facetime://contact name here"]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no public API to receive information from FaceTime. So it is not possible.

In general the information flow on iOS is one-way and always a push. So one app can call another app to open with additional information attached (like you do to open FaceTime) but you are not able to pull information from another app to your app. This has to be done by the other app via push (`openURL:`) as well.

Comment: Too bad. Thanks for confirming it.